# Confusion on number of bits in binary string (Python)

Tags: python, binary, byte, bit

I have a binary string `b'\xa8LeW'`, and I was attempting to look at the 'actual' binary string (e.g. just the 1s and 0s), by doing the following:

`bin(int.from_bytes(b'\xa8LeW', byteorder=sys.byteorder))`
which yielded `0b1010111011001010100110010101000`. From my understanding, `0b` is a prefix to indicate it is binary, and the rest is the binary string. However no matter how many times I count, I only see **31** bits after the `0b`, however, `len(b'\xa8LeW')` yields `4`, meaning 32 bits, and

```
x = bin(int.from_bytes(b'\xa8LeW', byteorder=sys.byteorder))
x.count("0") + x.count("1")
```

yields `32` bits. Here is the string again split up into bytes, except for the last 7 bits:

`0b 10101110 11001010 10011001 0101000`

I am expecting 4 bytes, so why is python counting the amount of bits I expect, but when I look at the string I seem to be missing one?

Comment: Leading zero bits aren't shown.

Comment: `0b0101 == 0b101`

Comment: didn't know that, thank you

Comment: Note that `x.count("0")` is counting the extra 0 in `0b`, offsetting the discrepancy.

Comment: You may always format the output the way you want: `x=int.from_bytes(b'\xa8LeW', byteorder=sys.byteorder)` and then `s = f'{x:032b}'` will show the leading zero(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it was mentioned in the comments, the leading zeros are skipped and they don't change the value:

```
>>> 0b1
1
>>> 0b01
1
>>> 0b0000001
1
```

You can format the output to add them:

```
>>> x = int.from_bytes(b'\xa8LeW', byteorder=sys.byteorder)
>>> f"{x:032b}"
'01010111011001010100110010101000'
```

There is also [int.bit_length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) method for `int` to check the bit length:

> Return the number of bits necessary to represent an integer in binary,
> excluding the sign and leading zeros:
>
> ```
> >>> n = -37
> >>> bin(n)
> '-0b100101'
> >>> n.bit_length()
> 6
> ```

```
>>> x.bit_length()
31
```